# Historic Road Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I would like to know if there is any data repository that can provide historic road data, starting from 1995 to 2017? The location of the data can be arbitrary, except United Kingdom. Also, I am looking for as much possible hierarchically available roads, with main focus on major road, secondary, connector etc. I have also looked on https://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/full-history/, but the data that are provided do not fit on my requirements.

I want to compare different street networks in different time intervals, thus the starting date must be between 1995-2000 in order to capture the slow rate of a road network's evolution.

Comment: What road data? Just where roads are (location), or any other properties? What hierarchy? In what form do you want the data? Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your question.

Comment: I am looking for line features, attached on it their hierarchy. I am mainly focus on major roads, secondary, connector etc., but If they are classified in more categories I don't really mind. All geospatial forms of data are acceptable (shapefile, gml, geojson etc.)

Comment: could you explain why openstreetmap data is not adequate?

Comment: If you want to compare road networks of different years, datasets between the years 2013 to 2017 are not adequate. The rate of change of a transport network is much slower, so you need to look for much older networks. A network of 2013 compared to 2017 will not have any significant change. The results won't be robust. In 4 years only a small portion of roads has been added without any huge change.